# strtotime function not returning value needed

Tags: php

I am having a problem getting the code below to work basically what I am doing is checking to see if the value of a time stamp variable that is in 24 hour format is after `1:00 PM` if it is then convert it to the 12 hour format. When I have the value echoed back it always says 6:00 PM. What is the problem?

Here is how I get the `$timeToday` variable

```
$timeToday = date("H:i A");
```

Here is the code that is not working correctly:

```
 if ($timeToday>"12:59"){
            $timeConverted = date("h:i A", strtotime($timeToday));
            echo "You clocked out at: " . $timeConverted . "<br>";
        } else {
        echo "You clocked out at: " . $timeToday . "<br>";
        }
```

Comment: Funny that is always says 6:00 PM but at a glance I would say you might want to use timestamps in your comparison. I don't think comparing strings will give results in a greater or less than context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing 2 strings, which do not have the same format. $timeToday is AM/PM, while you're comaring it to a 24h clock.

Also the code would print AM/PM either way. If I understand you correctly, you don't want to print AM, only PM.

```
 $format = strtotime($timeToday) > strtotime("12:59") ? "h:i A" : "h:i";
 $timeConverted = date($format, strtotime($timeToday));
 echo "You clocked out at: " . $timeConverted . "<br>";
```